# Angular Google Maps component changing options not working

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm using the google maps component and displaying several google maps marker components in it. I have the mapMouseOver(hover) event which is supposed to change the opacity of the marker, however it isn't working. I've tested the event and it is firing properly, it's just the one line `marker.setOpacity(0.5)` isn't taking effect. Also, the `this.manager.markers` is of type `google.maps.Marker[]`

```html
<google-map
  [options]="options"
  [width]="'100%'"
  (mapClick)="this.manager.onMapClick($event)"
>
  <map-marker
    *ngFor="let marker of this.manager.markers"
    [position]="this.manager.getMarkerPosition(marker)"
    (mapMouseover)="marker.setOpacity(0.5)" // Here's the problem
    (mapMouseout)="this.manager.onMarkerExit(marker)"
    (mapClick)="this.manager.onMarkerClick(marker)"
  ></map-marker>
</google-map>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround. In the component ts file, I used `@ViewChildren<MapMarker>` to reference the components and then used the `MapMarker.marker` property to reference the marker objects from those components. Using these objects, the changes took effect. My guess as to why the first approach wasn't working is that the `*ngFor="let marker of this.manager.markers"` might be creating copies of the this.manager.markers markers and using them instead of the this.manager.markers markers.